# The "like" tag is used for various meanings

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [like](/questions/tagged/like) tag is being used to mean [facebook-like](/questions/tagged/facebook-like) as well as SQL's LIKE keyword.

There are about 246 questions on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com tagged as [like](/questions/tagged/like), when they should mean [facebook-like](/questions/tagged/facebook-like), and about twice that much on the unfiltered view of Stack Overflow.

Could a retag be done, at on least Facebook Stack Overflow, so that they refer to the right usage?

Comment: It would probably be best if the [like] tag was blacklisted so that people must choose either [like-operator] or [facebook-like]

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like 0 reaming. Achievement completed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Currently I rettaged 245 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Achievement completed

The biggest problem is, that SE software do not allow you to submit edit/question without non-FB-related tag.

[image]

I'd propose to delete this limitation. It would allow users to use tags [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and there would be no problems

Comment: There is a reason why a question is required to have at least one tag that doesn't start with "facebook"; having all tags starting with "Facebook" would be as having all tags starting with "drupal" on Drupal Answers, which is a SE site only for Drupal questions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Tags from [drupal.se] do not "leak" into SO. These do.

Comment: I think this is a separate issue and should be discussed in a separate question.

Comment: @Tibbits. I still think it is not such a good idea, but I did it. [Let users post only facebook-related tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104075) - if t here are some negative votes, I'll delete that question imediatelly

Comment: There's no problem if you do this from the main site... And when you're cleaning up a tag, you probably *want* to use the main site so that there's no server-side filtering of questions being applied.

Comment: @Cody yes, I used it now

Comment: It is not problem at all. Questions on SE are about programming, not about using Facebook. So either the question is off-topic or it has at least one adequate language tag.